# Cascade Property Changed

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm

I have a form with a binding on it:

```
  <TextBox
      x:Name="txtGroupName"
      Height="23"
      Margin="96,13,10,0"
      VerticalAlignment="Top"
      TabIndex="0"
      Text="{Binding UserLevel.Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
      TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

Using MVVM there is a view it it bound to, containing the following:

```
        public UserLevel UserLevel
        {
            get { return _userLevel; }
            set { _userLevel = value; OnPropertyChanged("UserLevel"); OnPropertyChanged("SaveButtonEnabled"); }
        }

        public bool SaveButtonEnabled
        {
            get { return UserLevel.IsValid(); }
        }
```

However when the textbox value is update, even though it is bound to UserLevel.Name, the UserLevel property is the view is never set. The text value is set (i.e. Name) but even though the view and class behind it have Property Updated on it the SaveButtonEnabled is never run. I know i could probably but a Property in the View call Name which then updated UserLevel, but doing this seems counter intuative, surely there is a better way.

It seems like I want to cascade the PropertyChanged event.

Thanks in advance.

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changes in the textbox won't fire the OnPropertyChanged in the setter of UserLevel, because the UserLevel propertie never changed.
The TextBox is Bound to the Name-Property of UserLevel, so only the PropertyChanged of the Name property of the UserLevel (if its implementing property change) will be fired.

As you already wrote, one way to solve this is to add a Wrapper Property in the View:

```
public string Name
{
   get{ return UserLevel.Name;}
   set{ UserLevel.Name = value;  OnPropertyChanged("SaveButtonEnabled")}
      
}
```

and bind this property to the TextBox.

the second option, and i think the better option, is to use a Command for the SaveButton:

https://jigneshon.blogspot.com/2013/11/c-wpf-tutorial-command-bindings-and.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

In CanExecute, you can return UserLevel.IsValid()